# How to store QR image in a mobile database

Tags: android, sqlite

I am developing an android app for mobile , in which i have to store a qr image in a mobile database . when i scan the same qr image the next time it has to be compared with the database and provide the necessary details . Since qr image is unique for each entity it can be set as the `primary_key`. I would like to know if it is possible to implement such a concept if so please help me to store the qr image in a mobile database.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use the db4o database concept. there you can store objects instead of text, integers, and so on.
Maybe this will work for you (didnt test it yet).

Answer (score 0):

You could hash the data which is stored in the QR code (e.g. with MD5/SHA1/...). Then you just save the generated hash in the database.

An example how to create such a table:

```
 CREATE TABLE qrcodes (hash TEXT PRIMARY KEY); -- you might want add some additional fields
```

If you scan a new code, you generate the hash of the second QR code and compare it to the ones stored in the database. As hashes are (almost) unique and short, you can find the row about a specific QR image very quick.